# Is it possible to use Flyway with ODBC and C++?

Tags: c++, odbc, flyway

I see in documentation that Flyway works with Java and jdbc. However, our project uses SQLServer with ODBC and C++. Thus, is it possible to use Flyway in such a case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should be able to use it no problem with the command-line tool: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/

Comment: But exactly this page speaks abot JDBC:
"JDBC drivers
Flyway ships with JDBC drivers for the following databases by default:"
So, it look like I need special ODBC drivers for this command-line tool.
Thank you

Comment: No. Flyway will access your DB via JDBC and your c++ app via ODBC. Flyway ships with JDBC drivers for most DBs out of the box.